# Heap Space Exception on Downloading a File

Tags: java

I have an application in which if i download few entries , then the downloading of my csv file is  working fine....but if there are lot many entries, there is java exception  and on debugging it is giving vmdisconnected exception.
I am trying to get all the data in a variable named

```
String content = service.generateCSV(SearchVO);
```

this content variable is set in action class  and then i have a downloadservlet class in which i am getting this content variable.

```
String content = (String) request.getAttribute(CONTENT);
```

Can anyone suggest me how to read the content in a way that so  i can download a file even if it has lot many entries

This is how i am getting data from database

```
    `while (sqlRowSet.next()) 
        {
  data = (DB2Xml) sqlRowSet.getObject(Constants.TABLE_NAME_XML);
   dl = data.getDB2XmlString();}
```

The stack trace:-

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.fc.getDB2XmlString(fc.java:187)
```

Comment: Please post the java exception.

Comment: Please provide more code. If you want some help, so please format your code etc. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I beleave you are storing to large data in one memory-block. Provide more code and the Exception-Stacktrace.

Comment: @ckuetbach.yes i am storing all the data in content variable ....can you suggest me how to get it stream by stream

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is that you are trying to process a source that is too big to be used in one time in memory.

One approach to solve that problem could be to read your source (and process the data) gradually (for example line by line), instead of all in one time.

This is an example of how to read a file from a url gradually (line by line) and copying it to another file:

```
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(location);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                 new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(saveFile));
                String buffer;
                while ((buffer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    out.write(buffer);
                    // write the file or do whatever you want with it

                }
                in.close();
                out.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running out of heap space you will need to increase it. 
Here is a nice read on how to do it and how to avoid common mistakes:

http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, you want to move towards using streams of data, rather than putting all of the data into memory at once.

It looks like `service.generateCSVContent` produces a giant string, and from the stack trace it looks like this is coming from a DB2 database?  From a 2 minute search it looks like there is a [stream-based API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.java.doc/doc/c0021817.htm).  Perhaps using that will help solve your problem.  You'll just need to make sure you stream the content between A and B, rather than trying to put the whole contents in a variable.

Comment: ....what is A&B here ......i don't want to mess with db because i am using the same database query for my search results

Comment: A is probably the database.  Get stuff from the database as a stream (e.g. record by record, rather than everything at once).  B is whatever you are doing with it the other side (for example, generating the CSV file).  Generate it row by row, rather than all at once.